# MeteorJS - How to serve static files?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am building a MeteorJS application, and am trying to serve static images, css files, and other things. For some reason, my application cannot see any files in the "client" folder which is what I would expect the static folder to be, or any other folder for that matter. I also don't see any configuration files anywhere for me to set it, either. I am using the default setup that is generated using the "meteor create" command. Can someone please tell me where static files are served by default, or how to set the static folder in MeteorJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static, public folder in meteor is called `public`. See
https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories.